# How to show different text in the same activity? eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an app in which, dialog pops up and user selects an option. based on this option, next activity opens up in which there is some text. There are lots of options for the user to choose from in the dialog. Every option is intended to have the same layout just the text is different. Do I need to make these many new activities or can I somehow change the string based on user's choice by adding some conditionals somewhere? Please help﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not create separate activity for each user input, as the layout is same. You can achieve this by using a `TextView` and changing its text according to user input like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.<YourTextViewID>);
textView.setText("SetTextAccordingToUserInput");
```

**One Activity is sufficient.** Set the text on selection event in dialogue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to link both java files? As I have implemented a dialog in main.java file. onclick() method handles the option chosen by the user and each option opens another activity through intent. Now this new activity contains my text. How can I make this java file know which option was chosen by the user? Do I make some super global variable that I change in one java file and use its value as conditional in the other file?

Comment: As I said, you do not need to create a separate activity. On the click of dialogue button, just update the TextView in the same activity. It is an overhead to create and call a new activity just to show the same view(TextView is same), until and unless it is extremely needed.

Comment: Oh, you mean just change the text in the same activity and make the buttons invisible after the dialog. Yes, that can be done, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `Activity` with content and create this activity with parameter depend on user selection in dialog.

To open activity with parameter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("yourParameter", 1);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then to use it in your SecondActivity.class onCreate method

```
onCreate(Bundle instance)
{
// some stuff like setting layout ant etc.
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("yourParameter");
}
```